# Does Apache Ignite support strong consistency in SQL mode?

Tags: ignite

In this [post](https://www.gridgain.com/resources/blog/apache-cassandra-vs-apache-ignite-strong-consistency-and-transactions) the authors say that Apache Ignite supports strong consistency and they list a code sample which uses key-values. But I was unable to find a mention of the same in the [docs](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/sql-reference-overview) for SQL. 
Does Apache Ignite support strong consistency in SQL mode? If it does, will I be able to use it's other features (transactions, ACID properties) with strong consistency turned on? What is the performance hit by having full consistency turned on?

Any pointers to the right documentation will be very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this reply on the [Dev mailing list](http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Is-strong-consistency-supported-in-SQL-mode-tp32153p32177.html) Apache ignite SQL is strongly consistent but is not transactional

Answer (score 2):

In short, Apache Ignite has an experimental transactional SQL and MVCC support, though it's not recommended to use it in the production environment. I'd suggest you use the cache API for now if you need strong consistency.

From the MVCC [docs](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/multiversion-concurrency-control):

> Beta version of Transactional SQL and MVCC In Ignite v2.7,
>   Transactional SQL and MVCC are released as beta versions to allow
>   users to experiment and share feedback. This version of Transactional
>   SQL and MVCC should not be considered for production.

SQL transactions (BETA) docs: [here](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/SQL/sql-transactions) and [here](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/transactions)

Comment: Note, that the Gridgain's docs are fully compatible with Apache Edition.